# How to get parent categories from an entry?

Tags: categories

I have a pretty standard type entry page (`_entry.html`) which displays the details of an entry having navigated to it through 2 levels of categories. On this page I'd like to be able to query the two immediate category parents of this entry (sub-cat & cat) for use in a breadcrumb and page title variables.

I'm not sure how to approach this, or what the correct dot syntax is - I'm just getting up-to-speed with Craft CMS.

Any tips/references?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have a Categories field associated with the entry, you can get all of the related categories in your template via `entry.myCategoriesField` (replace with the actual Categories field handle).

So here’s how you would loop through all of them:

```
{% for category in entry.myCategoriesField %}
    <li><a href="{{ category.url }}">{{ category.title }}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
```

If you just want the last 2 categories, you can use Twig’s [slice](http://php.net/array_slice) filter:

```
normal syntax:
{% for category in entry.myCategoriesField|slice(-2) %}

shortcut syntax:
{% for category in entry.myCategoriesField[-2:] %}
```

If you want to set these categories to their own variables, so they can be referenced later on in your template, you could do this instead:

```
{% set parentCategory = entry.myCategoriesField.last() %}
{% set grandparentCategory = parentCategory.parent() %}
```

Comment: Aha, got it - I'm such a noob! Wasn't aware I could use negative syntax with 'Slice' either. Thx.

Comment: One further question regarding this: I can see how I can employ this for use in a breadcrumb, but if I wanted to assign the category titles (there's 2 of them) to separate variables so I can use them elsewhere in my template, how would I go about this? I know I can use "entry.myCatField.first()" but stuck on how to query the parent. TIA

Comment: @Britchie Lots of ways to do this but I just updated my answer with what I think would be the simplest/most readable one.

Comment: Those are really useful snippets and should solve my issue - thx so much for the follow-up Brandon.